# System.InvalidOperationException when using Keyboard.IsKeyDown() in Main

Tags: c#, multithreading, keyboard

I'm making the game snake in a console application and the game is supposed to refresh(the snake must continue moving) after a second or so.
this is why im using Keyboard.IsKeyPressed() because when i use Console.ReadKey() it stops the program without it bein able to continue. this is what the code for the movement looks like in Main:

```
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Up))
            Snake.Move(ConsoleKey.UpArrow);
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Down))
            Snake.Move(ConsoleKey.DownArrow);
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Left))
            Snake.Move(ConsoleKey.LeftArrow);
        else if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.Right))
            Snake.Move(ConsoleKey.RightArrow);
        else
            Snake.Move(ConsoleKey.Backspace);
```

it is places inside a while loop while backspace is simply something i pass so it will refresh and continue in the same direction without actually moving differently. but when i do this i a System.InvalidOperationException The calling thread must be STA,after some professional googeling i couldnt find out a way to solve this any help would be appriciated.and an explenation for SAThreads aswll :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding an [STAThread] attribute to your Main method:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you that was extremly simply :)